# html css3 resolution error

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I am helping a guy create a website for him. He has a resolution of 1920x1080 and I have a resolution of 1024x768 and well he is saying the tables are stretched out quite a bit, as well as an issue in the posting section. It is hard to explain the problem i mean you can look at the website here http://www.fvforumtest.forumotion.com  He has two pics that he sent me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U67zt.png
and
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Oer0.png

I'm not sure what could be causing these mess ups since I am seeing everything perfectly fine on my monitor. We checked to see if it was a cross browser efficiency issue, though it is not. He is seeing the above issues on all browsers and I'm seeing fine on my browsers.

You can sign in as

Acct: tester2
Pass: testingaccount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Issue 1 - background image stretching***
I guess his complaint would be the fact you're using *background-size:100% 100%* on an image that only 800px wide in the first place. So on a 1920px wide resolution, this is going to stretch to nearly 90% of 1920 pixels (1728px) - hence the appearance of stretching.

To fix this, either make the graphic larger in the first place, or modify your graphic so it doesn't need to stretch to the whole width.

***Issue 2 - message text cut off***
I'd say this is because you've absolutely positioned *smiley-box*, and it's width is 22%. 80% (#textarea_content) + 22% (#smiley-box) is not 100%, so overlapping is bound to happen.

***Issue 3 - Scroller hidden***
Hard to say. Have you tried to style the scroller (e.g. custom color etc)? This might be the problem. Remove all styling from the scrollbars if that's the case, and slow build up if necessary. I'm sure you just need to play with the styling a bit to get that to work.

Comment: ooo ok. I will try and fix that. See I couldn't see the stretching of the image on my computer. Let's try this and see what he says, he's in another country so we will have to wait completely for an a check mark answered :)

Comment: ok so I fixed that in the sense. Now what about the posting section??? Maybe my CSS has errors I presume, it could happen when I try and fly through it haha

Comment: Answer updated, feel free to share the love (+1)

Comment: I will share the love lol. Yeah I saw that it was 22% and 80% my bad haha. See I told you fly through it bound to be problems. Though I fixed it it was 1) absolute positioning with the size parameters 2) alot of the float lefts were causing a major issue. Fix the coding to my belief waiting on the guy to get back to me. Unless you want to check it out again Chris Bell.

Comment: There's no point me checking it again, I never actually saw these issues on my screen (I also share a smaller resolution). I just envisioned that these would be the issues from just examining your CSS. Well that's me done for the day, don't forget to mark as accepted :)